# Binding data to gridview ? Column not found?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net, while binding data to gridview it is giving error. Saying no column exists.

How can I restrict if there is no column in coding level.

Comment: You're saying you still want the column to be displayed, you just want it to be blank for every row if it's not in the bound data source?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to just add the missing columns to your bound data source.

The *much harder* way is to bind to a data source that enumerates a type that implements [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx).  This will let you control exactly how columns are mapped.  This is how `DataView` and `DataRowView` are implemented internally.